# How to know how much data for writing to file system is pending in the system on Linux system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, sync

I have a need to know how long the machine would take for the write cache to be flushed to actual disk. Right now, when I try to unmount a disk, unmount waits for sync to complete. On USB stick, this takes really long time (like up to a minute). Even for mechanical disk, this can take a few seconds. And, sometimes even the command comes back, the system is still writing out the cache to disk, it seems.

The safest and predictable way is, just to know how much cached data is pending on the system and wait for that to go down to zero. "sync" command does flushing but I'd like to know how much data is actually pending before running "sync" command.

I have a need to let the user know when it's safe to eject/pull out the disk.

EDIT: Seems like a way to do this is to watch /proc/meminfo's Dirty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> just to know how much cached data is pending on the system

You can see that for example with `cat /proc/meminfo` and look at the amount of dirty (modified, but not written back) pages.

> On USB stick, this takes really long time (like up to a minute).

Which is the fault of the USB stick - writing to Flash Storage is slow, even though modern USB sticks often have an intermediate buffer with faster access speed so they can pretend to have faster write times.

> And, sometimes even the command comes back, the system is still writing out the cache to disk, it seems.

No. When `umount` completes, all data for that partition is written.

> The safest and predictable way is, just to know how much cached data is pending on the system and wait for that to go down to zero.

This isn't predictable - the time still depends on the write speed of the device. So it will take however long it takes the Flash Storage to write all of this.

And if you just wait without using `sync` or `umount`, writes may be delayed. So waiting will always take longer then telling the system "please write all modified data back".

> I have a need to let the user know when it's safe to eject/pull out the disk.

The safe way is to do `umount`, when it returns, you can pull the device. If you want to be *really* safe, you can additionally use `eject`; that will fail if something is still mounted, it will sometimes visibly change the state of the device.

**Edit**

If your main problem is that you want to give the user an estimate how long it will take until he/she can take out the flash drive, then:

1) Do `eject` (if the variant you have on your system also automatically calls `umount`, like described it the comment; otherwise do `umount`).

2) Wait until `eject` returns, then show the user a message "you can take out the flash drive now"

3) At the same time, use a second process to scan `/proc/meminfo` for the "dirty memory" size repeatedly with some given delay (1 second or so). Remember the initial dirty size, use current dirty size as an estimate to completion (it should go towards zero), so you can show a progress bar.

Comment: *"use `eject`; that will fail if something is still mounted"* according to [man eject](https://linux.die.net/man/1/eject) it will try to unmount any mounted partitions first - *"If **eject** determines that the device can have multiple partitions, it will attempt to unmount all mounted partitions of the device before ejecting. If an unmount fails, the program will not attempt to eject the media."*

Comment: Thanks. I'm writing an app to mass-produce USB sticks for my volunteer work, and people using it is not necessary a patient type. I'd like to let them know how much they have to wait before pulling USB stick out. I am finding the time it takes for a flash drive to be ready for eject varies greatly so, if it's taking a long time, I want to give them how much to expect.

Comment: @lx07: They seem to have added that feature to `eject` since the last time I used it and it failed (which was quite a few years ago). Not sure if I like it better that way.